# How can I assign an active or closed label to a study in SQL when each study can open and close multiple times?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following data:

| Study ID | Effective Dt | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 174739 | 1/13/2000 | OPEN TO ACCRUAL |
| 174739 | 2/15/2002 | CLOSED TO ACCRUAL |
| 174739 | 5/22/2002 | SUSPENDED |
| 174739 | 8/3/2012 | OPEN TO ACCRUAL |
| 174739 | 5/21/2013 | CLOSED TO ACCRUAL |
| 174739 | 4/1/2022 | CLOSED |

A study can have multiple status at a given date. It can open and close to accrual (enrollment of subjects) multiple times. I am trying to figure out how I can categorize a study as "active" or "complete". If a study doesn't have a "CLOSED" status yet, that means it is still an "active" study. I don't know what the logic would look like.

"CLOSED TO ACCRUAL" doesn't mean that the study is complete, only the "CLOSED" status means it is complete.

I'm thinking there needs to be a Fixed LOD calc somewhere but I am lost.

Comment: Tags suggest you use MySQL database and Oracle SQL Developer tool. Is that correct? It would probably help if you posted desired result based on sample data.

Comment: *A study can have multiple status at a given date.* You **must** have any expression in your table which allows to set the ordering of such records. Without this the task is unsolvable. PS. Or you mean that "given date" <> "the same date in different rows", and `(Study ID, Effective Dt)` is unique?

Answer (score 0):

> If a study doesn't have a "CLOSED" status yet, that means it is still an "active" study.

`COUNT` the number of `'CLOSED'` statuses:

- if there are no `'CLOSED'` statuses then it is `'active'` and
- if there is a `'CLOSED'` status then it is `'inactive'`

You can do that with conditional aggregation and `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT study_id,
       CASE COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'active'
       ELSE 'inactive'
       END AS is_active
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY study_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (Study_ID, Effective_Dt, Status) AS
SELECT 174739, DATE '2000-01-13', 'OPEN TO ACCRUAL'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174739, DATE '2002-02-15', 'CLOSED TO ACCRUAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174739, DATE '2002-05-22', 'SUSPENDED'         FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174739, DATE '2012-08-03', 'OPEN TO ACCRUAL'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174739, DATE '2013-05-21', 'CLOSED TO ACCRUAL' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 174739, DATE '2022-04-01', 'CLOSED'            FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, DATE '1970-01-01', 'OPEN TO ACCRUAL'   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| STUDY_ID | IS_ACTIVE |
| --- | --- |
| 174739 | inactive |
| 123456 | active |

---

If you want to know whether a study is active at each time it was updated then use the same technique but with analytic functions (rather than aggregation):

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       CASE COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'CLOSED' THEN 1 END)
              OVER (PARTITION BY study_id ORDER BY effective_dt)
       WHEN 0
       THEN 'active'
       ELSE 'inactive'
       END AS is_active
FROM   table_name t
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| STUDY_ID | EFFECTIVE_DT | STATUS | IS_ACTIVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | OPEN TO ACCRUAL | active |
| 174739 | 2000-01-13 00:00:00 | OPEN TO ACCRUAL | active |
| 174739 | 2002-02-15 00:00:00 | CLOSED TO ACCRUAL | active |
| 174739 | 2002-05-22 00:00:00 | SUSPENDED | active |
| 174739 | 2012-08-03 00:00:00 | OPEN TO ACCRUAL | active |
| 174739 | 2013-05-21 00:00:00 | CLOSED TO ACCRUAL | active |
| 174739 | 2022-04-01 00:00:00 | CLOSED | inactive |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xMF_8uIZ)